# How to make a windows xp bootable?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, bootable-media

I need to install windows xp from an USB flash drive but it's has been really difficult to find a software that make the flash drive bootable. I've tried a coulpe of them, feew I've tested today:

1. ISO2USB
2. unetbootin
3. powerISO
4. win2flash

But neither worked. I'm trying using [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25129) iso.

Why this isn't working? what am I missing? Could you recommend me one which actually works for windows xp?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, according to many texts I've read, boot an ISO image from a usb. This is because an ISO image is made specifically for CDs, but USBs use a different format.

Therfor to fix your problem boot from a CD once you burn the ISO to the cd; Or find an ISO file specifically for a USB.

UPDATE: The link you have provided is not a bootable image, but rather an install disk for SP3 RUNNING XP already.

Comment: Doesn't exist any software that can take one of that ISO for CD and someway convert to an USB one? I'm pretty sure this is what the XP bootable versions around does...

Comment: @Jack you are right. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a program called Rufus. I use it every time, no problems..

Just select the XP iso and it will automatically customize the options for Windows.

Comment: Which ISO did you used? I tried this one but I get the error saying the ISO isn't bootable. If you know any software to make an ISO bootable

Answer (score 0):

I have used this before, and I am pretty sure I used unetbootin at least once. It works fine, but there are some things you need to check:

1 - the ISO image is bootable;

2 - your computer supports booting from external USB drives AND the option is set in system BIOS, with priority over internal Hard Drive;

3 - your USB flash drive/card reader can be detect by the system BIOS during P.O.S.T. (Power On Self Test)

I would recommend you to try with Ubuntu images, which can be downloaded and installed for free. That way it will be possible to determine what is wrong in the process.

There is a great reference here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: I don't know to make that XP ISO bootable. I managed to make it work with Windows 7 and Ubuntu only XP that I can't make working